# How to change profile data through out application, after changing from settings

Tags: android

I am stuck into this problem,please suggest a solution,

In my application user has settings page (activity) from where they can change profile data like name,profile photo etc..,
Now after user updates his information and comes back to home activity there is still old data is showing up, how can I update this information when user comes back to home.

Comment: Show the code that loads the profile data in the "home" activity.  Also show the code that sets the profile data in the "settings" page.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the `protected void` [onResume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29) method of your Home Activity and fetch the data there (instead of in the onCreate i guess). This way it gets updated everytime you revisit this activity

Comment: that is ok, but need to change only when profile has changed, this will fetch data every time I leave activity and then come back.

Comment: then you could set a `boolean changed = true` if options where changed, and test it in your `onResume()`, `if(changed)` update the data.